# Javascript Footprint Meaning

Tags: javascript, npm

Recently, I am studying Javascript `Just` library. In the `angus-c/just` GitHub, there is one sentence in README which is `Use Just if you care about JavaScript footprint (and none of the above applies)`.

User mentioned `JavaScript footprint`. What's the meaning of this JavaScript footprint at this point?

Link: https://github.com/angus-c/just/blob/master/TRADEOFFS.md

Comment: A long time ago in an small kingdom a wizard was curious about a given webpage. He opened his devtools and inspected it, it had dozens and dozens of external scripts, each one having hundreds of lines of code, on top of several small inline scripts, so many that he couldn't count them all. He concluded that that page had a huge JS footprint.

Answer (score 1):

It's the size of the JavaScript the page requires. See sense #5 in [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/footprint):

> *computing*
>
> the amount of resources, such as disk space and memory, that an application requires